# Maven: skip test but still fails on surefire

Tags: maven, surefire

I dont know if this is a question or suggestion. But I am going to ask it as a question cos may be i am doing something wrong.

My problem was that I wanted to skip tests in maven build, In eclipse plugin I checked the Skip Test option in configuration when running maven. It was still failing on the Test surefire plugin as it couldn't download the version 2.4.3 (even though my previous maven project used a 2.7.2 and it was already there in my repo) So i tried with skipping tests and it still failed.

I configured my POM to use the 2.7.3 plugin of surefire which i already had and it went forward only to say Skipping Tests. Now, my confusion is that when it was already going to SKIP the test part why bother going into the download and confirming if the plugin for surefire is there or not. Just Skip it I say..

well, Is that the normal behavior of maven that when you skip something the plugin is still downloaded as if you are going to use it. Or was I doing it wrongly that made it download it.

May be because there was something new called "Effective POM" and it contained a listing of surefire plugin 2.4.2 in the plugin management area, when i imported my maven project in eclipse using the m2eclipse and i couldnt edit the Effective POM. I had not seen this before in the NetBeans when making the maven project.

In order to work i added an unnecessary surefire plugin entry in my build profile and skipped the tests there as well and added the version that I had in my repo already. I only did this so that my project can be built under eclipse as well. other wise my project works in NetBeans and simple command line without any issues.

Any comments!!

I think maven should be able to see first the SKIP part and then proceed into the usage of the plugin.

Syed..

Comment: Can you post the error messages you got ? And the pom (in excerpts) would be helpful.

Comment: the error was only stating that it couldnt download the surefire plugin 2.4.3 and asked me to download i manually and add it manually. So i used the 2.7.2 (sorry it was not 2.7.3). Now its working as i added it in my POM. the eclipse plugin had a new section in Pom.xml called the Effective POM which had this 2.4.3 plugin version in its pluginmanagement section. I over rode it by adding 2.7.2 in my actual POM. (The effective POM was an uneditable POM i think that eclipse actually uses along with mine.)

Comment: The effective pom is the super pom of maven mixed with the current pom of your project. To be more accurate your pom inherits the things from the super pom. You can output this on command line as well via mvn help:effective-pom ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you mentioned you didn't understand the difference between using a plugin and configuring the plugin. In this case you are using the plugin (it's in your build area or as you already figured out coming via super-pom). Furthermore you are trying to skip the tests despite the fact that [maven-surefire-plugin in version 2.7.3](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3a%22maven-surefire-plugin%22) does not exist.

The configuration parameter skip will not execute the tests as well as not compile them. If you wan't just ignore the tests for a limited time you can use the "skipTest" parameter which in contradiction to skip will continue to compile the tests.

I would recommend to use a pluginManagement section of your project or your parent pom to define the version of the maven-surefire-plugin (which in the meantime exists in version 2.12)...

The following snippet add the pluginManagement part to a pom which controls which version of the maven-surefire plugin will be used.

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.11</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
    ..
  </build>
```

After you inserted that into your project pom the output effective pom should give you the version...otherwise you might need to update the project configuration first.

Comment: I had the 2.7.2 from maven building and downloading its own repo by itself. looking at your link evev 2.7.2 is an older version. When i added the project into eclipse and using the maven plugin for eclipse it created an Effective POM for itself listing an OLDer version of the plugin. I guess it was hard wired into the eclipse plugin to confiure using 2.4.3. I see a lot of plugins that are in the Effective POM are actually very old. I have no control over the Effective POM so i cannot change anything in there.

Comment: The eclipse plugin has nothing to do with this, cause it's based in maven (super pom; as explained earlier).

Answer (score 0):

Compiling and running tests is part of the default [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) of maven.  Since maven uses surefire to do run tests, it needs to download surefire. `skipTests` is not a maven configuration, but a surefire plugin configuration. The plugin determines that maven needs to `skip tests`.

As for 2.4.3 of surefire plugin, it is a [valid version](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.4.3/), but will work with `2.0.6` version of maven.  Most likely you are using a newer maven, but, for some reason have the `super pom` of the older maven version on your system.

Answer (score 0):

skipTest doesn't tell maven to skip the test lifecycle, it tells the surefire plugin not to run them. The plugin is still part of the lifecycle (it just does nothing when it's called). Hence your error.

If you want to NOT have surefire at all, you need to define your own packaging (since surefire is part of the standard jar packaging lifecycle) - which is a lot more work than just choosing a version of surefire that works for you (add a section with the right  in your  section).